# Quick question about sum of subspaces of a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I just have a quick question. Suppose there is $Z$, a Hilbert space, with $A$ and $B$ closed linear subspaces. If $(a,b)=0$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, I know that $A+B$ is also closed. I don't know how to prove it though.

I am just not sure where to start. Should I try to show the complement is open, or should I do something with sequences in $M+N$? I would really appreciate a little hint.

Comment: A closed linear subspace $F$ of a Hilbert space should always be identified with the orthogonal projection $p_F$ onto it. This is a bounded linear operator. And we have $F=\mbox{Ker} (I-p_F)$. Note that by assumption, $p_Ap_B=p_Bp_A=0$. Writing $x=p_Ax+p_Bx+(I-p_A-p_B)x$, we see that $A+B=\mbox{Ker}(I-p_A-p_B)$. Since $I-p_A-p_B$ is continuous, $A+B$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that every element of the space $A+B$ has a unique representation $a+b$ where $a\in A,b\in B$. Now consider any sequence of points in $A+B$, it can be written as $\{a_n+b_n\}_{n=1,2,3,\ldots}$. Suppose that 
$$\lim(a_n+b_n)=x\in Z.$$
It is enough to show that $x\in A+B$.
Let $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ denote orthogonal projections $Z\rightarrow A$ and $Z\rightarrow B$ respectively. Note that $\pi_A(a_n+b_n)=a_n$ and $\pi_b(a_n+b_n)=b_n$. Hence $\lim\pi_A(a_n+b_n)=\lim a_n=\pi_A(x)$ and $\lim\pi_B(a_n+b_n)=\lim b_n=\pi_B(x)$ (since projections are continuous). Therefore $\lim(a_n+b_n)=x=\pi_A(x)+\pi_B(x)\in A+B$. QED